# jOpenDocument: problems trying to generate PDF from ODS in

Tags: java, opendocument, ods, jopendocument

I have an .ods file and want to export it as PDF using jOpenDocument (Java).

I use following code:

```
                         // load the ODS file
        final OpenDocument filledCertificate = new OpenDocument();
        filledCertificate.loadFrom("filledCertificate.ods");

        // Open the PDF document
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        File outFile = new File("certificate.pdf");

        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

        document.addDocListener(pdf);
        System.out.println("test");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdf, fileOutputStream);
        pdf.addWriter(writer);

        document.open();

        // Create a template and a Graphics2D object 
        Rectangle pageSize = document.getPageSize();
        int w = (int) (pageSize.getWidth() * 0.9);
        int h = (int) (pageSize.getHeight() * 0.95);
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(w, h);
        System.out.println("test 2");
        Graphics2D g2 = tp.createPrinterGraphics(w, h, null);
        // If you want to prevent copy/paste, you can use
        // g2 = tp.createGraphicsShapes(w, h, true, 0.9f);

        tp.setWidth(w);
        tp.setHeight(h);
        System.out.println("test 3");

        // Configure the renderer
        ODTRenderer renderer = new ODTRenderer(filledCertificate);

        System.out.println("test 3.1");
        renderer.setIgnoreMargins(true);
        System.out.println("test 3.2");
        renderer.setPaintMaxResolution(true);
        System.out.println("test 4");                      
        // Scale the renderer to fit width
        renderer.setResizeFactor(renderer.getPrintWidth() / w);
        // Render
        renderer.paintComponent(g2);
        g2.dispose();

        // Add our spreadsheet in the middle of the page
        float offsetX = (pageSize.getWidth() - w) / 2;
        float offsetY = (pageSize.getHeight() - h) / 2;
        cb.addTemplate(tp, offsetX, offsetY);
        System.out.println("test 5");
        // Close the PDF document
        document.close();
```

When running, the console shows following:

```
StylePageLayoutProperties: Assuming Page Format A4: Width:  21.0cm
StylePageLayoutProperties: Assuming Page Format A4: Height: 29.7cm
StylePageLayoutProperties: Assuming Page Format A4: Width:  21.0cm
StylePageLayoutProperties: Assuming Page Format A4: Height: 29.7cm
test
test 2
test 3
PageHeigth:297000
[StyleStyle: name:co1 family:table-column cellProps:null                              masterTableName:null, StyleStyle: name:ro1 family:table-row cellProps:null masterTableName:null, StyleStyle: name:ta1 family:table cellProps:null masterTableName:Default, StyleStyle: name:Default family:null cellProps:null masterTableName:null]
Key:co1
Key:ro1
Key:ta1
Key:Default
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find Style name:null type:table-cell
at org.jopendocument.model.office.OfficeAutomaticStyles.getStyle(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.model.office.OfficeAutomaticStyles.getCellStyle(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.model.table.TableTable.getCellStyle(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.model.table.TableTableCell.computeStyle(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.model.table.TableTableCell.setRowAndColumn(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.model.table.TableTableRow.computeAllCells(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.model.table.TableTableRow.getCellsInRange(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.renderer.ODTRenderer.getPageWidthInPixel(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.renderer.ODTRenderer.updateSize(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.renderer.ODTRenderer.setResizeFactor(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.renderer.ODTRenderer.setDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.jopendocument.renderer.ODTRenderer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at jOpenDocument.createDocument.main(createDocument.java:82)
```

I have actually no idea which Style I can modify here? The instantiation requires only a OpenDocument as parameter.

Exception handling is already included (not part of the snippet).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by myself: I simply used an older version of jOpenDocument (1.3).